# Cannot change label text after performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a main ViewController which sends a String into a second view controller as so:

```
        if segue.identifier == "statsSegue" {
        let recievingVC:StatisticsVC = segue.destination as! StatisticsVC

        var recievingview:StatisticsView
        for View in recievingVC.view.subviews {
            if View is StatisticsView {
                recievingview = View as! StatisticsView
                recievingview.setLabel(data: "673")
            }
        }
    }
```

When the segue occurs, the label is properly displayed as 673. However, in the second ViewController, if I try to do a similar setLabel it does not change the label displayed:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let potato:StatisticsView = self.view.subviews[0] as! StatisticsView
    potato.GamesWonNum.text = String(580)
```

Disregard the potato variable, its a placeholder. `SetLabel()` in the first snippet above simply callse `GamesWonNum.text`.

So why does the label change correctly in the segue, but does not change in the `viewDidLoad` method of the viewController I am segueing into?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're accessing the views of `recievingVC`, that means `viewDidLoad()` will be called (hence the name view did load). And after `viewDidLoad()` is called, you change the label again to 673. To fix this, you could change the text in `viewWillAppear()`.

```
class StatisticsVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let potato = view.subviews[0] as! StatisticsView // You should just have "potato" as a property
        potato.GamesWonNum.text = "580"                  // GamesWonNum should be called "gamesWonNum"
    }
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "statsSegue" {
            segue.destination.view.subviews.forEach { ($0 as? StatisticsView)?.setLabel(data: "673") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. So accessing the views in the `prepareForSegue` will mean that the `viewDidLoad()` function is already called? Do I understand that right? And what exactly do you mean by "You should jsut have 'potato' as a property"?

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` will be called once the view of the view controller is being accessed, not just in `prepareForSegue`. Because you're accessing `potato` by using `.subviews[0]` I'm assuming you don't have `potato` as a property. If you did, you didn't need that line and could change the text by using `potato.GamesWonNum.text = "580"`.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much, that's a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to manipulate another view controller's view hierarchy. That violates the principle of encapsulation, an important OO concept. Instead, you should add properties to your destination view controller that you use to pass the information that you want to display,  and in your destination view controller's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear you should install the data.

Also, it's a bad idea to hard-code a view controller to expect a specific view at a fixed index in it's subviews. That's fragile. If you restructure your view hierarchy at a later date that code will break. Instead you should create an outlet or link it up, or set a tag on the view and use the tag to find the desired sub view.